# Is it necessary to sort seeds from chaff to save for planting?

Tags: seed-saving

Is it necessary to sort the seeds from the chaff if you're going to replant? Would just releasing the seeds from the chaff be good enough?

Comment: @YosefBaskin please don't try to answer a question in a short comment.  it does not provide a complete answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no! Depends on your current storing and sowing conditions as also, the plants you're wishing to grow. If you intend on sowing seeds right, soon after picking them up, it'd be better to simply add them along with chaff to the soil for more added organic content. If you prefer to store it, especially in a humid, closed conditions, the chaff will simply attract more moisture and your seeds will be exposed to moulds/ fungi. Make your call according to storing duration and humidity conditions.